# data source is not getting flushed in kendo ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using kendo auto-complete, in that i am binding data to data source remotely. each time when i bind data to kendo data-source it will not clear or flush the old data in data-source. Following is the code that i am using

```
$("#input3").kendoAutoComplete
({
    dataSource:new kendo.data.DataSource({

        cache: false,
        read:getPackage(document.getElementById('input3').value),
        data:pkg

    }),
    select: function(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    },
    filter: "startswith",
    placeholder: "Select Package..."
});

function getPackage(req) 
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: 'BookingCity.asmx/GetAllCountryforPackage',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data:"{'prefixText':'"+ req +"','id':'" + document.getElementById('cityName2').value+ "'}", 
        success: function(response) {
            pkg=response.d
        },

        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert(status)
        }

    });//ajax
}
```

Can anybody tell me the solution that how can i clear the old data in that data-source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data) method of the DataSource can be used to set the data. To make it empty you need to pass an empty JavaScript array:

```
var autoComplete = $("#input3").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autoComplete.dataSource.data([]);
```